# Get sharepoint images from URL

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online

I am trying to get the image from a URL as a BitmapImage but don't know how. The URL was in a list Sharepoint and I already retrieved like this:

```
public async Task<Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection> getListContent(string listName)
        {
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items;

            string userName = Settings.Default.User;
            string password = Settings.Default.Pass;
            string siteUrl = Settings.Default.URL;

            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
                {
                    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                }

                clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

                await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List TargetList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
                CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
                items = TargetList.GetItems(query);

                clientContext.Load(items);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            return items;
        }
```

One of these fields contains the url to an image in a sharepoint library and I am trying to retrieve it like this:

```
     public Model.Control createModelControl(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item)
        {
            return new Model.Control
            {

                BmpImg = new BitmapImage(new Uri((item["Image"] as FieldUrlValue)?.Url))
        }
```

When I inspect the result, this is what I have :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDPYW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MYoW.png)

I think I need to load it with a client context again, but am not sure of how to do it. With Sharepoint on premise, there was a method called "DownloadData" but it does not seem to exist with SPO...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to have it work, here is how:

```
public static BitmapImage DownloadDocumentFromSharepoint(string imgUrl)
{
    try
    {
        ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

        string userName = localSettings.Values["User"].ToString();
        string password = localSettings.Values["Pass"].ToString();
        string siteUrl = localSettings.Values["siteUrl"].ToString();

        using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
        {
            ctx.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);
            ctx.Load(ctx.Web, a => a.ServerRelativeUrl);
            ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();


            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File res = ctx.Web.GetFileByUrl(imgUrl);
            ctx.Load(res);
            ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();


            Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream fileContent = null;
            BitmapImage btmImgRes = new BitmapImage();


            ClientResult<Stream> data = res.OpenBinaryStream();
            ctx.Load(res);
            ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                if (data != null)
                {
                    data.Value.CopyTo(mStream);
                    mStream.Position = 0;
                    fileContent = mStream.AsRandomAccessStream();                            
                    btmImgRes.SetSource(fileContent);
                }
            }
            return btmImgRes;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("fail to download document from sharepoint");
    }
}
```